# npm don´t update to new version

Tags: node.js, npm

I´m facing a funny problem. I wrote a small module with some function to work with the xbee-api in nodejs. I created a git repository and published the module at npm website. I can see on github and npm the newest version (0.0.4) but neither npm install nor npm update install the new version.

Is there some time buffer before installing a new version? I also tried with --force but still 0.0.2 is the latest version which will be installed.

EDIT:

I found out that changing in package.json from ^0.0.2 to * the newest version will be installed.

But from my understanding, ^0.0.2 should install also all minor releases below 1.0.0. Is this correct?

Comment: no, it means that it is compatible with this version: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Comment: A thanks. But how can i add modules to my package.json with npm install --save to adjust this: I tried npm install xxx@latest --save but this didn´t work.

Comment: I guess there is no automatic way for this, but I may be wrong

Comment: Yes, seems so. I now install normally and change within the package.json to "*"